# Element-Wise Array Manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing what is essentially a video viewer; 320x320 video frames are stored in a custom file type which also contains some nonliner per-pixel correction data before the start of frame storage. The viewer is to be written in C#.

Currently I read the data from the file using Filestream.Read() and copy from the byte[] array to a ushort[] array using Buffer.BlockCopy(). All of that seems very efficient, but when it comes to apply the per-pixel correction data currently I am using a loop, with the following pseudocode:

```
for (pixel in pixels) {
     pixel_corr = pixel*pixel_gain + pixel_offset;
}
```

and that's really all there is to it. I do this for 6 frames at a time (video was recorded from 6 different angles), and the issue is that this processing can not keep up with real-time scrubbing. If I drag my frame selection slider even fairly slowly the frame updates can't keep up with the dragging. Of course one solution would be to recompute new frames not when the slider value changes but when the user stops dragging it - that would not, however, improve performance when I am in "play" mode.

Are there any solutions for improving the speed of this element-wise manipulation in C#?

Comment: You are compiling for RELEASE I assume? And have you tried using `unchecked { ... }` around your loop there?

Comment: Have you considered processing the frames in the GPU?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Release yes, but I can try `unchecked{...}` shortly.
@JamesBuck Unfortunately the machines that this is intended to run on don't have GPUs with compute capability.